# comparar 2 tablas rápidamente e insertar un 1 si son iguales

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola tengo este query:

```
 $select_1 = tep_db_query("SELECT referencia FROM tabla1") or die (mysql_error());
    $select_2 = tep_db_query("SELECT modelo FROM tabla2");
    //busco las coincidencias
    //numero que guardara las coincidencias
    $num = 0;
    //busco en todos los resultados de select_1
    while ($data1 = tep_db_fetch_array($select_1)) {
                        

    //busco en todos los resultados de select_2
    while ($data2 = tep_db_fetch_array($select_2)) {

        if($data1['referencia'] = $data2['modelo']){
            $num++;
            tep_db_query("update tabla1 set ya_esta = '1' where '" .$data1['referencia'] = $data2['modelo']. "'");
            tep_db_query("update tabla2 set ya_esta = '1' where '" .$data1['referencia'] = $data2['modelo']. "'");
        }
    }
    }
```

estoy tratando de insertar un 1 en 2 tablas al mismo tiempo si se cumple la condición

```
$data1['referencia'] = $data2['modelo']
```

esta es la tabla:

[image: esta son las 2 tablas]

y no hace nada, se queda el query en un loop infinito.

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de tus tablas? Se me hace que se podría hacer directamente en un SQL con el JOIN de las dos tablas.

Comment: Dependiendo de la cantidad de registros en cada tabla tu doble `while` tomara un buen tiempo. Si a eso le sumas que en los updates tus `WHERE` son siempre `true`; por cada coincidencia de `referencia` y `modelo` actualiza toda la `tabla1` y toda la `tabla2`.

Comment: Estoy pensando que podrías hacer un **join**. Dime...Tienen alguna relación los registros de la tabla1 con los de la tabla2?

Comment: Si la tabla1.referencia = tabla2.modelo, tengo 5mil registros y por cada coincidencia hay que insertar set ya_esta = '1' en tabla1 y tabla2

Comment: he editado la pregunta y coloque una tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente lo que estás buscando es un `JOIN` entre las dos tablas usando el campo `referencia` en uno y `modelo` en el otro para la condición de `JOIN`.

`SELECT modelo FROM tabla1 JOIN tabla2 ON referencia = modelo`
devuelve todos los valores de `modelo` en la `tabla1` que tienen su correspondiente `referencia` en `tabla2`.

Igualmente `SELECT referencia FROM tabla1 JOIN tabla2 ON referencia = modelo`
devuelve todos los valores de `referencia` en la `tabla2` que tienen su correspondiente `modelo` en `tabla1`.

Los dos devuelven el mismo conjunto de valores y puedes usarlos como condición en un `UPDATE`.

Entonces tus sentencias `UPDATE` quedarían así.

```
UPDATE tabla1 SET ya_esta = 1
  WHERE modelo IN (SELECT modelo FROM (SELECT * FROM tabla1) as t1 JOIN tabla2 ON referencia = t1.modelo);

UPDATE tabla2 SET ya_esta = 1
  WHERE referencia IN (SELECT referencia FROM tabla1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabla2) as t2 ON t2.referencia = modelo);
```

Ahora es cuestión de ejecutar estas sentencias en tu codigo `php` y listo.

Comment: una ? para recorrer toda la tabla utilizaria un while? es que tarda mucho no pudiera hacer esto mas rapido son 5mil productos en ambas tablas

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es tu necesidad de usar el php haciendo una consulta `SELECT`, recorrer los registros en un ciclo while y realizar un `UPDATE` por cada iteración cuando que el `SQL` te permite hacerlo todo de una vez. Por otro lado, me parece que hacer un UPDATE, o dos en este caso, es más rapido que 5000.

Comment: tienes razon, lo he ejecutado y me salta este error: Table 'tabla1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Editada la respuesta. Estoy un poco oxidado con el SQL

Comment: Cuidado, los `WHERE ? IN(SELECT` son sumamente ineficientes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes actualizar ambas tablas con una sola sentencia, haciendo `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tabla1 t1
  INNER JOIN tabla2 t2
    ON t2.referencia = t1.modelo
  SET t1.ya_esta = 1
    , t2.ya_esta = 1;
```